# How to use AWS SDK PHP for AWSECommerceService

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have to use following API URL to fetch Books information (found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html))-

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
  Service=AWSECommerceService
  &Operation=ItemLookup
  &ResponseGroup=Large
  &SearchIndex=All
  &IdType=ISBN
  &ItemId=076243631X
  &AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyID]
  &AssociateTag=[Your_AssociateTag]
  &Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
  &Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

I can use [PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html) for this, I could not find any doc on how to achieve this using SDK.

**EDIT**

Following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868551/517616) links, I have written following code-

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$ItemId = 1603843698;
$ResponseGroup = 'Offers';
//$Timestamp = gmdate("Y-M-DTh:m:sZ");
$Timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$AWSAccessKeyId = "EXAMPLEEXAMPLE";

$associateTag = "something-10";

echo $Timestamp;
echo "<br />";
$str = "GET\n
webservices.amazon.com\n
/onca/xml\n
AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSAccessKeyId."&AssociateTag=".$associateTag."&ItemId=".$ItemId."&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=".$ResponseGroup."&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=".urlencode($Timestamp);
$str = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$str,'my secrete',true)));

$url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Offers&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=".$ItemId."&AssociateTag=ebooksprices-20&AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSAccessKeyId."&Timestamp=".urlencode($Timestamp)."&Signature=".$str;
echo "<br />";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

But with no success, I get this output-

> 2016-07-14T09:50:06Z string(427) " SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the
>   service documentation for
>   details.34b23224-4750-46c7-8f75-929239f955de"

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got time to post my working code-

```
$ItemId = $_GET['isbn'];
$ResponseGroup = 'Offers';
//$Timestamp = gmdate("Y-M-DTh:m:sZ");
//date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$Timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$AWSAccessKeyId = "/your key/";

$AssociateTag = "/your-tag/";
$Version = "2013-08-01";
//echo $Timestamp;
//echo "<br />";

$str = "Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=".$ResponseGroup."&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=".urlencode($ItemId)."&AssociateTag=".$AssociateTag."&AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSAccessKeyId."&Timestamp=".urlencode($Timestamp);

$ar = explode("&", $str);
//var_dump($ar);

natsort($ar);
//var_dump($ar);

$str = "GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
";

$str .= implode("&", $ar); 

//echo $str;
//echo "<br />";
$str = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$str,'/your secret/',true)));

$url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Offers&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=".$ItemId."&AssociateTag=your-tag&AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSAccessKeyId."&Timestamp=".urlencode($Timestamp)."&Signature=".$str;
//echo "<br />";
//echo $url;
//echo "<br />";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//var_dump($result);

$xml=simplexml_load_string($result) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo "<h1>AMAZON API</h1><pre>";

print_r($xml);
```

This code returns the response in XML format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK's does currently not support the Amazon Product Advertising API.

For implementation there's a PHP code example provided by Amazon on this page: [Implementing a Product Advertising API Request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/ImplementinganA2SRequest.html)

For the request signature, follow this documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html. More specific details on a PHP implementation of the request signing has been answer here before: [Amazon Product API returns “SignatureDoesNotMatch”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868551/517616)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in that case i need to find `[Request Signature]`

Comment: @easycoder just stumbled upon this, might be useful: https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6006877

Comment: I already solved this, will answer when i get time, thanks for response :)